# Help on creating a University thesis cover

Tags: thesis, covers

I am new to LaTex.

I'm trying to create a thesis cover according to my University's guidelines. I think I am almost there. However, I need some help:

1. My name cannot be in bold;
2. How to increase the logo size;
3. How to put the text "Thesis to obtain a Master's Degree in Law, in
   the speciality of…" and "Supervisor...and Year and month" further up;
4. With `\date{\today}` I don't get the date.

I have tried my best and got this with my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{1cm}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{novalaw}
        \bigskip
           \textbf{Author's Name}
       \vspace{0.5cm} 
       \vspace{1.5cm} 
  \textbf{Thesis Title}
  \end{center}
\begin{flushright}
       \vfill   
       Thesis to obtain a Master's Degree in Law, in\\
       the speciality of…     
       \vspace{0.8cm}
 \end{flushright}    
        \begin{center}    
       Supervisor:\\
       Name\\
      \end{center}  
      \date{\today}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

My University requires like this:

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't want your name in bold, then don't use `\textbf`.

Comment: Yes. But with \author I get errors.

Comment: \author and \date are generally put into the preamble and are used to set up \maketitle.  Since you don't use \maketitle (good decision) you don't need them, nor will they do anything.

Comment: Why not to use \maketitle ?

Answer (score 1):

The following redefines `\maketitle` (you might want to hide the definition in some other file to keep your main file clean). This is just a sketch of your title page and might need some more fine tuning to match your formatting better, but it should get you started.

I defined the macros `\myspecialty` to set the specialty. It takes an optional argument defining the thesis type (should be either `doctoral` or `master`). The mandatory argument can be used to specify the specialty. If the value is `security` the "Doctoral Degree in Law and Security" is used.

The other macro I defined is `\mysupervisor` to directly specify the supervisor.

You can use the normal macros `\author`, `\title`, and `\date` to define those elements.

You might want to change the `example-image-duck` to the actual logo you need to use.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \textuppercase \text_uppercase:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \strifeqon \str_if_eq:onTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@myspecialty{}
\newcommand*\@myspecialtytype{}
\newcommand*\@mysupervisor{}
\NewDocumentCommand\myspecialty{O{doctoral} m}
  {%
    \gdef\@myspecialtytype{#1}%
    \gdef\@myspecialty{#2}%
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\mysupervisor{m}{\gdef\@mysupervisor{#1}}
\RenewDocumentCommand\maketitle{}
  {%
    \begin{titlepage}%
      \begin{center}%
        \includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}\par
        \vspace{1cm}%
        {\large\textuppercase{\@author}\par}%
        \vfill
        \vfill
        {\Large\bfseries\textuppercase{\@title}\par}%
      \end{center}%
      \vfill
      \null\hfill
      \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \raggedright
        \strifeqon\@myspecialtytype{doctoral}%
          {%
            Thesis to obtain a Doctoral Degree in
            \strifeqon\@myspecialty{security}%
              {Law and Security}
              {Law, in the specialty of \@myspecialty}%
          }
          {%
            \strifeqon\@myspecialtytype{master}%
              {%
                Dissertation to obtain a Master's Degree in Law, in the
                specialty of \@myspecialty
              }
              {\PackageError{mytitle}{Unknown degree type \@myspecialtytype}{}}%
          }%
      \end{minipage}%
      \vfill
      \vfill
      \vfill
      \begin{center}
        Supervisor:\\
        \@mysupervisor
        \vfill
        \@date
      \end{center}
      \vfill
      \null
    \end{titlepage}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{Author's Name}
\title{Thesis or Dissertation Title}
\myspecialty[master]{creating titlepages}
\mysupervisor{Dr. Maria da Silva, Professor of the NOVA School of Law}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. How can I have font Times New Roman, size 12 for the normal text, and title and my name, size, say, 20? By "you might want to hide the definition in some other file to keep your main file clean" what do you mean? I'm writing my dissertation in one file, so do you mean that I should a separate file for the cover?

Comment: @PietroP it is generally a good idea to keep a clean structure. In the main file just put stuff that is specifying the looks and use `\include{<subfile>}` for your chapters, `\input{<subfile>}` for files containing macro definitions and the like. Put each chapter into a separate file (using `\include`), best in a subdirectory. Don't put everything into a single file, this just becomes convoluted.

Comment: @PietroP unless you're using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX you'll have a hard time to get *Times New Roman* as your main font. Search for using Times (New Roman) in LaTeX to get some decent results. Same for arbitrary font sizes (like "20"), search for it. If you don't find a solution fitting your needs ask a new question. In this question you asked to reproduce the structure of your title page, something I have done. Keep your questions limited in scope and don't extend them via comments. That way you'll get better answers (and do your research, only ask when you're stuck).